# Adding field to collection if not exists

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{'flags': {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False: 'flag_3': True}
    'other_data': {....}}
```

In a single operation, I want to add a list of flags to the existing flags. If the flag already existed, I want to leave its value as is, otherwise it should be False.

For example after adding ['flag_3', 'flag_4'], the collection should look like this.

```
{'flags': {'flag_1': True, 'flag_2': False: 'flag_3': True, 'flag_4':False}
    'other_data': {....}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/)** as a way of streamlining your updates with some logic to get the flags which need to be added. Something like this:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0,
    flagList = ['flag_3', 'flag_4'];


db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var existingFlags = Object.keys(doc.flags), // get the existing flags in the document
        newFlags = flagList.filter(function(n) { // use filter to return an array of flags which do not exist
            return existingFlags.indexOf(n) < 0;
        }),
        update = newFlags.reduce(function(obj, k) { // set the update object 
            obj["flags."+ k] = false;
            return obj;
        }, { });

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": update
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
})

// Clean up queues
if (counter % 1000 != 0){
    bulk.execute();
}
```